# How do I set the regression line color in the r car scatterplotMatrix function

Tags: r, plot, colors

How do I change the color of the regression line in the r car scatterplotMatrix function?

If I run this code:

```
# Load the iris dataset.
library(car)
data(iris)
 
# Plot #1: Basic scatterplot matrix of the four measurements
scatterplotMatrix(~Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width, data=iris)
```

then I get this plot:
[image]

Inspection shows the points, the smooth windows, and the regression lines are all the same color and are not all very clearly differentiated.

If I wanted the points in blue, the regression in green, and the smooth in orange, how would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This just requires a careful reading of the documentation `?scatterplotMatrix`.

The part about color says:

> col
>   colors for points; the default is carPalette starting at the
>   second color. The color of the regLine and smooth are the same as for
>   points `but can be changed using the the regLine and smooth arguments`.

The description of `regLine` says:

> regLine=TRUE equivalent to regLine = list(method=lm, lty=1, lwd=2, col=col[1])

`smooth` is more complicated. The description is down in the **Details** section. That description is long, but includes:

> You can also specify the colors you want to use for the mean and
>   variance smooths with the arguments col.smooth and col.spread.

Putting this all together, you can get

```
scatterplotMatrix(~Sepal.Length+Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width, 
    data=iris, regLine = list(col="green"),
    smooth=list(col.smooth="orange", col.spread="orange"))
```

[image: Scatterplot with lines of different colors]

Comment: The documentation is not really unambiguous. Who's to tell me that the arguments `col.smooth` and `col.spread` can't be used in `scatterplotMatrix` instead of using them in `smooth = list(...)`.